# select query for exact time stamp

Tags: mysql

If i have several records of timestamp and want to get time stamp which is the closest to current date. What exact query command should I use? Thanks in advance. Below I depict my last query command:

```
mysql> select date_format(time_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) as Time_Stamp
       from log 
       where username='test' and Time_Stamp <= NOW();

                  | 2012-11-23 14:50:28 |
                  | 2012-11-23 16:39:45 |
                  | 2012-11-23 16:51:41 |
                  | 2012-11-23 16:58:43 |
                  | 2012-11-25 10:12:14 |
                  | 2012-11-25 12:50:38 |
                  | 2012-11-25 12:51:20 |
                  | 2012-11-25 13:15:44 |
                  | 2012-11-25 17:47:43 |
                  | 2012-11-26 09:24:46 |
                  +---------------------+
                  285 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I only want to get **2012-11-26 09:24:46**

Comment: You should substract current timestamp (as number) and timestamp (as number) in table and get abs() from that difference. Minimum abs value will be from closest timestamp.

Comment: @Kamil: Perhaps, could you please give the exact query command?

Comment: Sorry im not sure how to do it in MySQL and i dont have any server to test my idea. Probably for converting datetime to number you may use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime)` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably this should work (see the last line):

```
select date_format(time_stamp, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' ) as Time_Stamp
   from log 
   where username='test' and Time_Stamp <= NOW()
   ORDER BY Time_Stamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer if it answered your question!

Comment: @nickhar:Sure, apparently i will need round about 4 minutes to accept answer.